# MySQL Cluster Replication Merge

Tags: mysql, replication

We'd like to have two MySQL cluster groups, and at the same time have replication set up between them.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible setups you could try

## TOPOLOGY #1

- Data Center #1 with two(2) DB Servers (DB1, DB2)
- Data Center #2 with two(2) DB Servers (DB3, DB4)
- Setup DRBD with Each Data Center
- Setup MySQL Replication Between the DRBD Primaries
- Setup DBVIP (Linux Heartbeat/ Pacemaker / ucarp)

What this setup provides

- Synchronous Disk-Level Replication Within Each Data Center
- Asynchronous Replication Between Data Centers

## TOPOLOGY #2

- Data Center #1

  - Three(3) DB Servers (DB1, DB2, DB3)
  - [Percona XtraDB Cluster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23148/mirroring-databases-in-mysql/25759#25759) among the three(3) DB Servers
- Data Center #2

  - Three(3) DB Servers (DB4, DB5, DB6)
  - [Percona XtraDB Cluster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23148/mirroring-databases-in-mysql/25759#25759) among the three(3) DB Servers
- MySQL Circular Replication

  - DB3 used as Master to DB6
  - DB3 used as Slave to DB6
  - Use Semisync Replication Between Master and Slave

What this setup provides

- Virtually Synchronous Replication Within Each Data Center
- Asynchronous Replication Between Data Centers

I have discussed setups like this before

- `Feb 10, 2014` : [MySQL High Availability for InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58594/mysql-high-availability-for-innodb/58606#58606)
- `Jul 11, 2013` : [MySQL replication between datacenters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46158/mysql-replication-between-datacenters/46159#46159)
- `Dec 26, 2012` : [MySQL Replication and High Availability](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31031/mysql-replication-and-high-availability/31035#31035)
- `Oct 25, 2012` : [mysql read slave to fetch entire database on start](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27582/mysql-read-slave-to-fetch-entire-database-on-start/27611#27611)
- `Aug 20, 2012` : [Best solution for cross-datacenter MySQL master-slave replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22788/best-solution-for-cross-datacenter-mysql-master-slave-replication/22790#22790)
- `Mar 26, 2012` : [3 Databases, Best Replication Setup?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15573/3-databases-best-replication-setup/15577#15577)
- `Dec 19, 2011` : [Best way to setup master to multi master replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9424/best-way-to-setup-master-to-multi-master-replication/9425#9425)
- `Mar 29, 2011` : [MySQL high availability, failover and replication with Latency](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/mysql-high-availability-failover-and-replication-with-latency/1983#1983)

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!